# Is FileReader take more time to load?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Below is my code

```
var uploadIDImage = {
    IDPos: {},
    IDNeg: {}
};

var FR = new FileReader();

FR.onload = function(e) {
    console.log("123");
    console.log(e);
    $("#UploadIDPos img").remove();
        $("#UploadIDPos i").hide();
    $('#UploadIDPos').prepend('<img id="IDPosImg" style="width: 140px; height: 80px;"/>');
    var img = document.getElementById('IDPosImg');
  img.src = FR.result;
    uploadIDImage.IDPos.Files = FR.result.split(",")[1];
    console.log("11111");
};

if(e.target.files[0]) {
    FR.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);  
    if(originalIDPosSize === undefined) {
            var size = Math.round(e.target.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024);
            originalIDPosSize = size;
        }
        else {
            totalSize  = totalSize + originalIDPosSize; 
            var size = Math.round(e.target.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024);
        }
        var remainSize = totalSize - size;
        console.log("Remain size : " + remainSize);
        $("#remain-size").text(totalSize - size);
        totalSize = remainSize;
} 

console.log("22222");
console.log(uploadIDImage.IDPos.Files);
```

What I got from my console.log is first print "22222" and undefined and then "111111".

Why "11111" not print first?

Comment: Because `console.log("22222");` was executed first..

Comment: i see. the 2222 is print before FR.onload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your section of code `FR.onload = function(e) { ... }` is just defining a handler for the `FR` object.  The `FileReader` methods like `readAsDataURL()` are asynchronous -- your program continues after it executes the  `FR.readAsDataURL(...)` statement.

Then later, when the file reading is done, then the function you specified for `FR.onload` runs.  It is indeterminate whether this happens before or after your `console.log("22222");` statement.

Comment: how do i rewrite this code , after FR.onload, i still can use the FR. result?

Comment: If you want to do something after the load is complete, you need to do it in the FR.onload function.

Comment: Here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api is a pretty good walk-through on using the FileReader object.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
FR.onload = function(e) {... }
```

you are setting a callback on the `FileReader` which is called when the reading operation has successfully completed.

Now you script proceeds and runs `console.log("22222");`

After a while the callback is invoked and you see the `11111`.